# 2 divs offset because of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Issue #1**

Trying to make 2 divs align with eachother,

the fist div doesnt have a scrollbar, but the second has one. The scrollbar cause the second div to be offset from the first one.

Is there a way to align those 2 divs?

**Issue #2**

Why is the second div not scrolling when it has the overflow-y:scroll; ?

---

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fixed-top-container {
    text-align:center;
    top:0px;
    height:100px;
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:100px;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.content {
    width: 800px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

---

**View JSFiddle for issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Aaeijh/qAh9g/1/**

Answer (score 0):

> How can we get the bottom div to scroll?

Use the user friendly `<textarea>` instead of old `<div>` technique

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" class="container">
//your text here

</textarea>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/qAh9g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

remove `overflow:hidden;` and `overflow-y:scroll;` ..